# No-one *at all* understands me

Tags: word-order

Can I put *'at all'* in the mid-position?

My research: I found some questions connected with *'at all'*, but none of those were about what I'm trying to find out. Then I found some information about *'at all'* in the Cambridge Dictionary, but it also said I could put *at all* in the mid-position before an adjective, nothing about verbs. That is why this question occurred.

> No-one at all understands me.

> No-one understands me at all.

Comment: Note that **no one** must be written as two separate words with no hyphen.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney whatever the guide books may say, there is a strong British defence of 'no-one'. Brits hyphenate far more than the US, so hyphenating this raises no eyebrows. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no-one [Also:https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8741/noone-no-one-or-no-one which is more about the comments than the QA itself]

Answer (score 3):

The two examples (3 and 4) have different meanings.

In *No-one at all understands me*, the expression *at all* emphasises no-one. Theoretically it is redundant, as no-one already means zero, but I have seen the word reinforced this way.

In *No-one understands me at all*, the expression *at all* emphasises the lack of understanding. This is not redundant; the sentence *No-one understands me* can allow people to understand me in part. Adding *at all* makes the statement that nobody understands me even in part.